# Magento2 : How to add Observer for catch when new order placed

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, sales-order

I wanted to save the orders from `magento2` to my `local Database`.

I am planning to Create a `module` and `add Observer` to catch once a `order is placed`.

I don't know much about the `Events & observer`, just gone through this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html)

Please help me is there any `Event` already given by `Magento2` after `new Order`. if there is no default event for Order placement Where do I have to write a event for new order.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit:

> **app\code\Autosynch\Sale\registration.php**

```
<?php /**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register( \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Autosynch_sale',
__DIR__
);
```

> **app\cpde\Autosynch\Sale\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter.php**

```
<?php

namespace Autosynch\Sale\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $logger->info($order->getData());
        $logger->debug($order->getData());

        var_dump($order->getData());
        exit;
    }
}
```

> **app\code\Autosynch\Sale\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Autosynch_Sale" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

> **app\code\Autosynch\Sale\etc\event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="modulename_sales_order_place_after" instance="Autosynch\Sale\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Please help me where I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file `Autosynch/Sale/etc/event.xml` and put below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="autosynch_sales_order_place_after" instance="Autosynch\Sale\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And then create Observer class **OrderPlaceAfter.php** in `Autosynch/Sale/Observer`.

```
    <?php
    namespace Autosynch\Sale\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

    class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $_logger;

        /**
         * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $_logger
         */

        public function __construct(
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $_logger
        ){
            $this->_logger = $_logger;
        }


        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

            $this->_logger->info($order->getData());
            $this->_logger->debug($order->getData());

            //var_dump($order->getData());
            //exit;
        }
    }
```

Hope this help You.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will help to get started. I was wondering how I need to test and see how Data is coming, So need to parse it and Send to another service and Save Data in Oracle Database.

Comment: every time the order placed in magento, the observer will be called. You can analyze the order data by doing var_dump($order->getData()); exit; it will give array of order information.

Comment: Is there any way to debug to see the array data or to print some where. what this line will do `var_dump($order->getData());`. bu the way i need to do all my operations before `exit;` right?

Comment: You can create log . this http://www.thienphucvx.com/magento-2-logging-to-a-custom-file/ will help you.

Comment: I am getting this error `Fatal error: Declaration of Autosynch\Sale\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter::execute() must be compatible with Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface::execute(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\app\code\Autosynch\Sale\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter.php on line 11` Let me where I ma going wrong

Comment: Have you  done setup:di:compile

Comment: Yes, This error came When i did `setup:di:compile`

Comment: I have updated the Question, Can u Please check.

Comment: You should not pass logger in this way.

Comment: Let me update the proper way

Comment: Do we need to use constructor ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78684/discussion-between-jb-pakalapati-and-prasanta-hatui).

Comment: I have updated the observer class. Please use that

Comment: I am getting this error: `Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento- CE\app\code\Autosynch\Sale\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter.php on line 2` If possible Can you join chat

Comment: I have tried this, but It's not working as expected. I think your answer helped to get on track. Please let me know were I am missing here is my [code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230221/magento2-not-able-to-log-order-details-when-order-is-placed)

Comment: @PrasantaHatui  File name should be events.xml. You have given it as event.xml which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know how to create observer. You can catch event `sales_order_place_after` for your task.

[Reference](https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/)