# Magento2 : Not able to Log Order Details when order is Placed

Tags: magento2, log, exception, debugging

I am trying to print order details in Log /return JSON result when a new order is placed. Nothing is printing in `System.log` or in `exception.log`,

Please check my code below, Let me know where I am doing wrong.

> \app\code\Autosynch\Sale\registration.php

```
<?php /**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register( \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Autosynch_Sale',
__DIR__
);
```

> \app\code\Autosynch\Sale\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Autosynch_Sale" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

> \app\code\Autosynch\Sale\etc\event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="modulename_sales_order_place_after" instance="Autosynch\Sale\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> **\app\code\Autosynch\Sale\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter.php**

```
<?php
   namespace Autosynch\Sale\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

    class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $_logger;

        /**
         * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $_logger
         */

        public function __construct(
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $_logger
        ){
            $this->_logger = $_logger;
        }


        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

            $this->_logger->info($order->getData());
            $this->_logger->debug($order->getData());

            //var_dump($order->getData());
            //exit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created to `composer.json` for your  module.

Also, **observer definition file** name  is the wrong `event.xml`, it should be `events.xml`

second, to print an array, you should  use

> $this->_logger->log(100,print_r($order->getData(),true));

If you enable developer mode  or default mode then might be log print is not working

for log print, you can try to use [a custom log file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92441/4564)

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/order.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
$logger->info(print_r($order->getData(), true));
```

---

**Update Date :- 17th Oct, 2022**

for use Logger Method in **Magento version: 2.4.3+**:

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Catched event succssfully');
```